# I am trying to use search on my object in 3 fields name, category, and tags, so now similar item three time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

views.py

```
 if search:
     wallpapers = Wallpaper.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(category__category_name__icontains=search) | Q(tags__tag__icontains=search))
```

Html code

```
<form method="GET" action="/" class="d-flex">
  <input class="form-control me-2" name="search" id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you trying to shorten your query or do you get an unexpected result? It is not clear from what you posted above.

Comment: What is the question? What problem do you face?

Comment: I am getting same object three times,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that both the category and the tag match, and thus act as a "multiplier" for each other. You can work with [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve unique items:

```
if search:
    wallpapers = Wallpaper.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(category__category_name__icontains=search) | Q(tags__tag__icontains=search)
    ).distinct()
```